# Kivy custom widget to plot data, can't get current widget dimensions

Tags: python, graph, kivy, widget, dimension

I'd like to create a custom kivy widget that plots data in response to user input or live location data.
I need the current dimensions and position of the widget to draw the line, but I can't seem to get those correctly, and I can't trigger a line update either with a button click for example.

Here is a sample code, when button is clicked, the GraphWidget should plot the line.

```
import numpy as np
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class BoxLayoutMain(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.gw = GraphWidget()

    def plot_line(self):
        # called when user clicks button
        data = np.asarray([[0,0],[100,100],[200,50]]) # test data
        self.gw.plot(data, min_x=0, max_x=200, min_y=0, max_y=150)

class GraphWidget(Widget):

    trace_points = ObjectProperty((0, 0, 0, 0))

    graph_w = NumericProperty(100)
    graph_h = NumericProperty(100)
    graph_x0 = NumericProperty(0)
    graph_y0 = NumericProperty(0)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        # dimensions are correct here:
        self.graph_w = self.width
        self.graph_h = self.height
        self.graph_x0 = self.pos[0]
        self.graph_y0 = self.pos[1]

        self.test()

    def test(self):

        # dimensions are also correct here:
        print('W ', self.graph_w)
        print('H ', self.graph_h)
        print('X ', self.graph_x0)
        print('Y ', self.graph_y0)

        # a test line is drawn when triggered by on_size method
        self.trace_points = [400, 0, 600, 500]

    def plot(self,data_xy, min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y):

        # called when user clicks button
        # dimensions are not correct here:
        print('W ', self.graph_w)
        print('H ', self.graph_h)
        print('X ', self.graph_x0)
        print('Y ', self.graph_y0)

        # transforming data points to pixels, needs correct widget dimensions/position:

        xf = self.graph_w / (max_x - min_x)
        yf = self.graph_h / (max_y - min_y)

        X = (data_xy[:, 0] - min_x) * xf  + self.graph_x0
        Y = (data_xy[:, 1] - min_y) * yf  + self.graph_y0

        nps = np.column_stack((X, Y))

        # line is not drawn/updated
        self.trace_points = list(nps.flatten().astype(int))


class GraphTestApp(App):
    pass

GraphTestApp().run()
```

The kv file:

```
BoxLayoutMain:

<BoxLayoutMain>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    Button:
        text: 'Click'
        on_press: root.plot_line()

    GraphWidget:

<GraphWidget>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            width: 2
            points: self.trace_points
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the line:

```
self.gw = GraphWidget()
```

in the `__init__()` mthod of `BoxLayoutMain` is creating a new instance of `GraphWidget`, and that instance is not in your GUI. So any reference to `self.gw` is not relevant to the `GraphWidget` in your GUI. You just need to get a reference to the correct instance of `GraphWidget`. One way to do that is by using `ObjectProperty` and `ids`. You can modify your `BoxLayoutMain` to have an `ObjectProperty` named `gw`:

```
class BoxLayoutMain(BoxLayout):
    gw = ObjectProperty(None)

    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    #     self.gw = GraphWidget()
```

And the `__init__()` method is no longer needed. Then add the `ids` to your `kv`:

```
BoxLayoutMain:

<BoxLayoutMain>:
    gw: gw  # set the gw ObjectProperty to the widget with id of gw
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    Button:
        text: 'Click'
        on_press: root.plot_line()

    GraphWidget:
        id: gw  # id used above to get a reference to this GraphWidget

<GraphWidget>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            width: 2
            points: self.trace_points
```